# Сериализация моделей pydantic с переводом имен полей в camelCase

Tags: python, pydantic, pydantic-2.x

Есть сервис на Java и клиент на Python. Сервис принимает/отдает json с именами полей в camelCase стиле, в соответствующих pydantic моделях на Python хотелось бы использовать snake_case (идиоматично для Python).

Пробую делать модель с псевдонимом (alias):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Test(BaseModel):
    test_test: str = Field(..., alias = "testTest")
```

При таком коде при инициализации модели требуется указывать имена полей по алиасу (в camelCase), а при сериализации выводитcя в snake_case:

```
test = Test(testTest="test")  # При указании test_test выдает ошибку валидации Field required [type=missing, input_value={'test_test': 'test'}, input_type=dict]
print(test.model_dump())
```

Вывод:

```
{'test_test': 'test'}
```

Мне нужно наоборот, чтобы инициализировать можно было по обычным именам (в snake_case), а сериализовалось в camelCase. В идеале, чтобы не нужно было прописывать алиас для каждого поля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы использовать обычные имена полей при инициализации, нужно добавить в модель настройку `populate_by_name=True` ([документация](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.populate_by_name)):

```
class Test(BaseModel):
    test_test: str = Field(..., alias="testTest")

    model_config = ConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)
```

Чтобы сериализовалось с алиасами полей, нужно указать параметр `by_alias=True` (см., параметр by_alias в [документации метода `model_dump`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_dump), аналогичный параметр есть у метода `model_dump_json` и у соответствующих методов класса [`TypeAdapter`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/type_adapter/) - актуально, если нужно через тайп адаптер сериализовать, например, список объектов):

```
test = Test(test_test="test")
print(test.model_dump(by_alias=True))
```

Вывод:

```
{'testTest': 'test'}
```

Чтобы автоматически генерировать алиасы, можно функцию конвертации строки из snake_case в camelCase указать в поле `alias_generator` в конфигурации модели ([документация alias_generator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.alias_generator), в модуле `pydantic.alias_generators` есть несколько готовых функций конвертации, в том числе для конвертации в camelCase):

```
from pydantic.alias_generators import to_camel

# Аналогичный конвертер реализованный "на коленке":
# def to_camel(string: str) -> str:
#    words = string.split("_")
#    return words[0] + ''.join(word.capitalize() for word in words[1:])


class Test(BaseModel):
    test_test: str

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        alias_generator=to_camel,
        populate_by_name=True,
    )
```

Если конфиг модели становится громоздким и постоянно повторяющимся во всех моделях, можно его вынести в отдельный класс, и этот класс указать базовым для всех моделей вместо `BaseModel`. Полный пример:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, Field
from pydantic.alias_generators import to_camel


class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        alias_generator=to_camel,
        populate_by_name=True,
    )


class Test(MyBaseModel):
    test_test: str


test = Test(test_test="test")
encoded = test.model_dump(by_alias=True)
print(encoded)
decoded = Test.model_validate(encoded)
print(repr(decoded))
```

Вывод:

```
{'testTest': 'test'}
Test(test_test='test')
```